# Change GET vars to url path in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want a rewrite rule to be able to change a GET variable into a nicer url.

For example:

**example.com?category=news** *to:* **example.com/category/news**

I also want other GET variables to be left alone.

Example:

**example.com?category=news&sort=asc** *to:* **example.com/category/news&sort=asc**

The modifications need to take place in the wordpress htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I don't want to redirect, I just want the url to to change.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried Jon Lin's example. It worked, but I'd like to add a /en before and I'd also like the category to be a varaible.

I tried the [Mod Rewrite Generator](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php), i got this result, but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ /en/?category=$1 [L]
```

Next I tried to combine the two, but I'm not any closer to figuring out what the problem is.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(index\.php)?\?/en/category=$1&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /en/category/%1?%2 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)$ /en/?category=$1 [L,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: If it can't be done with .htaccess, I'm open to using PHP. However, it needs to work in Wordpress.

Comment: There's no way to change the URL in a browser's location bar *without* redirecting

Comment: What i meant to say was, the url as far as PHP is concerned is still the original one but the one seen by the user is the nicer one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules **before** the wordpress rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(index\.php)?\?category=news&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /category/news?%2 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^category/news$ /?category=news [L,QSA]
```